# Rest Sharp Deserialize Partial Object

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, restsharp

I'm trying to deserialize part of a request with custom serializer using RestSharp. I create a new rest client and Add my customer Serializer

```
protected void SetJsonHandler(IRestClient client)
{
    var jsonHandlerType = "application/json";
    client.ClearHandlers();
    var jsonDeserializer = new JsonNetDeseralizer(JsonSettings);
    client.AddHandler(jsonHandlerType, jsonDeserializer);
}
```

I have request to get accounts which looks like so:

```
public List<Account> GetAccounts()
{
    var request = new RestRequest("accounts/", Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);
    var response = this._client.Execute<List<Account>>(request);

    this.HandleKnownExceptions(response);
    return response.Data;
}
```

I have models which match the property names

```
public class Balence
{
    public Double Amount { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }
    public AccountType Type { get; set; }
    public Balence Balence { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

but they won't map because the models is nested in the data property:

```
{  
   "pagination":{  
     "ending_before":null,
      //...
   },
   "data":[  
    {  
       "id":"gje99c1e-7081-5784-9a1e-4p302b92312b",
       "name":"ETH Wallet",
       "primary":false,
       "type":"wallet",
       "balance":{  
          "amount":"0.97845347",
          "currency":"ETH"
       },
       "created_at":"2017-10-01T16:50:51Z",
       "resource":"account",
    }],
}
```

**EDIT**

the Json Deserializer:

```
public class JsonNetDeseralizer : IDeserializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializerSettings settings;

    public string RootElement { get; set; }
    public string Namespace { get; set; }
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }

    public JsonNetDeseralizer(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content, settings);
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to not have to make a dummy model with a data property to have it map. Is there an easy way to configure Rest Sharp, Json.Net to map the Data Property to the models in

Comment: @BrianRogers It's just a simple wrapper on json.net.  I've edited the question with the details

Comment: I am a little confused by the API and how they interact. The currently shown code is too disjointed.

Comment: @Nkosi the RestSharp client, is set to use the custom json deserializer.  When the RestClient calls execute it executes the request passed in, and uses the deserializer.  My issue is that the Model I'm attempting to deserialize to `List<Account>`  doesn't represent the json returned because Coinbase Wraps there data in a data object.   So basically the deserializer works if I wrap the List in a dummy object with a property `T Data`

Comment: My initial though was to use a custom json converter that is aware of the wrapper and extracts the data

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, for now I’ve added just a generic wrapper, but that custom converter probably would be a better idea because they do that for every request :/